# MySQL query BOOLEAN MODE Case Sensitivity

Tags: mysql, search, case-insensitive

My search is case sensitive, but I want it to be case insensitive. In MySQL I have my database and table set to `utf8_general_ci`. The search is still case sensitive. I have been doing some research and it seems the reason behind this is `BOOLEAN MODE` in my query. Is there a way to make it case insensitive? so no matter how I type any word with any sensitivity it will always bring it up in the search result?

```
SELECT 
        s_cost_sheet.partnumber,
        s_cost_sheet.description,
        s_cost_sheet.price,
        s_cost_sheet.notes

    FROM s_cost_sheet
    WHERE MATCH ( partnumber, description, price, notes ) 
    AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY partnumber, description, price, notes ASC";
```

I have tested the search in phpMyAdmin and it works no matter how a type the word plate, it can be Plate, PLATE, plaTE. It all works fine, so it must be something within this that is causing the issue.

Comment: What about the columns? Are they also in utf8_general_ci?

Comment: yes, they are also set to utf8_general_ci

Comment: I think without double quotes this should work well. Why do you use percent symbols?

Comment: with '.search.' it still is case sensitive. I pull results, but only if i use exact sensitivity. for examle. I am searching for plate, but results wont show, because its entered in as Plate. so I have to search Plate for it to show up. I want it to to find anyword no matter what (PLATE, plate, Plate, PLate, etc). How I have it, it should work, so I am not understanding the issue on why its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the columns is of type int or numeric then the search becomes case sensitive. Also there's no need to use % in the searched string

Comment: Yes this is correct. I changed them all to VARCHAR rather than using 2 columns as decimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TRY changing your table and column to `utf8_general_ci` and you don't have to use `%` wildcard with `FULL TEXT Search`

**RECOMMENDATIONS**
Also avoid using a lot of columns with `ORDER BY` clause if you need quicker results.

Comment: I have the table and column set to utf8_general_ci and it still acts in this way.